# Screen saver issue

Tags: multiple-monitors, screensaver, screen-corruption

When I leave my PC alone for while the screens turns black, which is fine. When I return and move my mouse it comes back on but my second screen stays black and my first screen has a blue overlay over the top of the unlock screen.

I believe this is to do with my dual screens on gts450.
screen 1 is 1920*1080
screen 2 is 1024*768
The blue overlay is on screen one and looks to be the size of screen 2

I can put the password in and press enter and then everything goes back to normal, but how do I fix this issue of a blue overlay stopping me seeing whats on screen?

Comment: Does this happen with ubuntu 12.04? Which version are you currently using? Have you tried booting with ubuntu 12.04 live cd/usb and check if the same thing happens?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug. There is already a bug report in launchpad, although launchpad might not the right place for it (probably this is a gnome-screensaver bug and has to go upstream).

https://bugs.launchpad.net/gnome-screensaver/+bug/1061787

Comment: If the downstream bug has the necessary details to make a good upstream bug, then anyone can go ahead and post an upstream bug based on it and linking to it. Downstream in Launchpad, it can be connected to the upstream bug report with "Also affects project".

Comment: @EliahKagan Yeah, you are right. It wasn't worth it to mention this here. I added "gnome-screenshot" already as "affected project" but did not write add upstream bug, because I'm not sure enough about the problem and the other bug reports. I'm still quite newbie here. I'm currently working on it, I'll try to add more information then.